# How to find out which module to import rxjs classes and functions from quickly in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

There are times I try some example angular code when there is `rxjs` involved, there are `Observable` and other `operators` that I have to import. When it is simple, it is fine.

But when there comes `onUnsubscribe` or `debounce` or some new stuff not so common, I couldn't know where to import it from?

How can I find out where to import quickly?

Comment: In Angular 5 with angular-cli 1.5 and RxJS 5.5 you can import all operators from `rxjs/operators`

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio to develop the angular application, then there's an extension available to auto import the modules. The name is "Auto Import" by steoates.